# Add Ready-To-Use Business Process link and Add Product button not exist, why?

Tags: dynamics-crm

In order to use some out of the box Business Processes in Dynamics CRM 2015(On Premise), i have to go to: 
Settings > Data Management
And click on Add Ready-To-Use Business Process link, but this link not exist!
[image]
I Googled a lot and all of it says how to enable and using it, but none of them mentioned its possible that this link might not be exist!
What i suspect is that my CRM base language is not English and in all of English based language CRMs its ok and this link is exist.
Also Add Product button for Product not exist, only Delete and other stuff.
Is this it and my CRM must be English based language? and there is no other reasons?

Comment: Are you using the Dynamics CRM cloud version (Dynamics 365) or an On Premise installation of Dynamics CRM? Do you have an administrator role?

Comment: @Atzmon On Premise and yes i have full admin access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 different things: Product creation & Ready to use Business Process

Product creation is not possible other than Base language. It is how [CRM is designed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn817861.aspx#BKMK_CreatingOrUpdating). You can have a look at [Similar discussion](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/161044) and up-vote this [MS Idea](https://ideas.dynamics.com/ideas/dynamics-crm/1308602).

> Records with localized attributes are read-only unless your preferred language is the organization’s base language. You can only create records with localized property values using the organization’s base language. If you update the base language value for a localizable attribute any localized values for that attribute are not changed except if you clear the value for the base language. If you set the base language value to null or an empty string, all localized values for that property will also be cleared.

Regarding the Ready to Use BPFs, I could see an [option](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/dynamicscrmsupportblog/archive/2013/10/29/fixing-the-missing-business-process-flow-translations-of-non-base-languages-after-upgrade-to-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2013-online-only) to enable it in base language & use transaltions (though I never tried this & it says only online but there is no harm to try it).

Comment: OK, well unfortunately it is what it is ha :(